# Low Disk Space notification, how can I stop that?

Tags: disk-space

I had formatted my drive to create Drive E:, wherein I will be putting my files.

It's 15 GB, then I encrypted almost 14.999gb of it, I know that its really Low Disk Space, because I created an ecrypted folder in it.

1. How can I stop the notification from popping out all the time.
2. Is it bad for the drive that I encrypted almost the whole Drive E, out of 15 GB, only left is 2 MB?

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555622):

How to disable the low disk space warning messages

To disable these balloon messages follow the steps below:

1. Open the Registry Editor by clicking on Start -> Run and running REGEDIT.
2. Navigate to the following location:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\ Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
3. Right-click in the blank area of the right-hand pane of the Registry Editor and create a new DWORD Value by selecting New -> DWORD Value.
4. Name this new DWORD Value NoLowDiscSpaceChecks
5. Double-click on the new DWORD value and assign it a value of 1.
6. Close the Registry Editor and restart the computer.

For the second part, no, just don't store anything there.

Comment: I just tried it, then restarted my laptop, but the same notification keep on popping out. By the way, Im using Windows 8..